# How to use 'this' at this selection in d3?

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, this

I just found this example in d3 and I am not really sure what is the reference of

> this

in this function?  Usually you got a selection on an elemente first, and then this is a reference to that DOM element. But in this case of the function, i clearly don't know what kind of reference

> this

is used for
Thanks for the help.

```
  function highlight(d) {
 d3.select(this).select(text).classed('active', true);};
```

Comment: There is no difference here: `this` is still the DOM element. The function is simply creating a selection with `this` and selecting its text child element (assuming that it's actually `"text"`, not `text`). Also, the first argument is unnecessary here.

Comment: Thank you, Gerado. One last question. When you say, the function creates a selection with "this". But what kind of selection exactly? A selection of what? Do you mean elements? At this point, it seems to me, that it is a selection of an empty placeholder?

Comment: `d3.select(this)`... this is the selection I'm talking about. It's a selection containing the DOM element passed to `highlight`.